# react select error on upgrade: TypeError: dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-select

I have just updated the react-select library and I have found out that It doesn't work anymore. On [the official site](https://react-select.com/upgrade) I found this *Upgrade guide* which doesn't help me and which says nothing.

I've also checked the [samples on their site](https://react-select.com/creatable), but it gives me the same error.

for example I want to do a very basic creatable select:

```
import AsyncCreatableSelect from 'react-select/async-creatable';

const promiseOptions = (inputValue: string) =>
  new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('searching...');
    }, 1000);
  });

const Select: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <AsyncCreatableSelect
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
    />
  );
};
```

Same for all the others selects I have in my project. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

The error I receive is the following:

[image]

I use `nextjs 12.1.2` `react 18.0.0` and `typescript 4.6.3` and `react-select 5.2.2`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem seems to be the fact that I use `react 18.0.0` with `react-dom 17.0.1`

In order to solve the problem above, just update the `react-dom to 18.0.0`

Comment: in case, i don't want to upgrade to react 18 or react-dom 18. what is fix?

Comment: I'm seeing this error after upgrading to  "react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
Not sure how I can fix this

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the Hot Module Replacement (HMR) setting.
I used Material UI on Typescript with webpack. I added HMR blindly to the webpack config and this error appeared by running webpack-dev-server.
`react` and `react-dom` were at the same 18.2 version.

I solved it by removing the HMR completely from webpack.config.js.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by updating my react-dom:`npm i --save-dev react@18 react-dom@18`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I resolved it by installing react-dom. Make sure you have both dependencies, "react" and "react-dom," in your "devDependencies" (not just in "peerDependencies"), and ensure they are installed correctly.

> `npm i --save-dev react@18 react-dom@18`

Sources:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18327